# How to create a User Role that behaves like customer role in Woocommcers

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im creating a "seller" role in a woocommcers site and I want it to have the same privileges at a "customer" role

Currently when I use this code

```
add_role('seller', 'Seller', array(
    'read' => false,
    'edit_posts' => false,
    'create_posts' => false, 
    'delete_posts' => false,
));
```

The user created has accecess to a limited Wordpress admin backend which I do not want

I also tried this function to remove the Wordrpess admin backend access it kinda works but still has the admin header at the top

```
function wpse23007_redirect(){
  if ( is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX') && ( current_user_can('seller') ) ){
    wp_redirect(home_url());
    exit;
  }
}
add_action('init','wpse23007_redirect');
```

Is there a way to create a new "Customer" role in Woocommcers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add customer roles capabilities to the seller role by

```
$wp_roles = wp_roles();

$customerRole = $wp_roles->get_role( 'customer' ); // Copy customer role capabilities

$role = 'seller';    
$display_name = 'Seller';
add_role( $role , $display_name , $customerRole->capabilities );
```

Comment: This works better then my code but it but it has the same limited access to the admin backend when the customer role never shows any wp admin dashboard stuff also when I create a seller account role it doesn't let me login at all but the user is in the database

Comment: We have given similar customer role capabilities to the seller role as requested. Customers are not allowed to access WordPress dashboard so the seller will automatically can't access the same. If you want the seller to have access WordPress dashboard then you must assign seller other role capabilities.

Comment: Your answer is right editing user roles does not flush privileges when changes are made you need to remove_role( 'seller' ); and start over. After I removed the role and re added the role it worked